# Error in installing Cuda Toolkit Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install Nvidia package and CUDA Toolkit in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have installed Nvidia driver and on running :

```
nvidia-smi
```

it shows my driver version is 384.111 and it seems the same is perfectly installed.

Now, I'm trying to install Cuda Toolkit 9.1. The same is causing a problem. I am going to tty1 and the stopping lightdm. Thereafter, I'm trying to run the ".run" file downloaded from

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=runfilelocal

I am getting the following error:

```
Checking for libEGL
Got EGL_VENDOR string "NVIDIA", expected "DUMMY VENDOR"

An incomplete installation of libglvnd was found. Do you want to install a full copy of libglvnd? This will overwrite any existing libglvnd libraries.
```

I would like to request any suggestions on what steps should I follow. For your info, I had earlier purged all Nvidia files before installing the driver.

Comment: How are you installing the NVIDIA drivers?  From a `.run` file or from the `graphics-drivers ppa`?

Comment: I installed the nvidia drivers from the run file...NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.42.run file. This successfully ran. Now, I'm trying to install Cuda Toolkit .run file, which is cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run

Comment: I only asked that because on Ubuntu I couldn't do it from a run file either.  I actually ended up installing the drivers from the ppa instead.  I helped someone recently in the comments here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1016876/downgrade-to-kernel-4-4-in-ubuntu#comment1649732_1016876  I am thinking I need to write something up as an answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any libglvnd packages in the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, so you must have gotten the incomplete installation of libglvnd from some other software source, possibly from the Nvidia files that you had earlier purged, if not from some other package that uses GL graphics library. So allow installing a full copy of libglvnd in order to make sure that NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 9.1 works properly.

Comment: Thanks, karel. It would be great if you could suggest where could I download/how could i install libglvnd package again.

Comment: Is it an acceptable solution if I were to delete libglvnd?

Comment: I recommend deleting the existing libglvnd or simply overwriting it with the new one. You can also get libglvnd from the Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 repositories. There's nothing much for dependencies, so it looks like you can just download whatever libglvnd .deb files you want from [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglvnd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and manually install them.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the best command for manually installing .deb files is `sudo apt install ./package.deb` because it automatically resolves dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Before trying to reinstalling the package, i unpackaged the .run file and split it to two - .run for driver and .run for samples. THen I installed. It seems the install was successful. Now, the nvcc path needs to be updated.

Comment: [Nvcc -v fails but CUDA 7.0 installed and nvcc present](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673124/nvcc-v-fails-but-cuda-7-0-installed-and-nvcc-present)

Comment: Sure. Thank you again. I made a mistake and updated a wrong path to environment variable "cuda-9." instead of "cuda-9.1". Now everything seems to work good as of now. Thanks a lot.